# Quarkus BeanManager with unit test

Tags: java, java-8, cdi, quarkus

BeanManager does not return beans during unit test in the use case describe above. The project is a Java library.

Bean interface

```
public interface My {
  String turn();
}
```

Bean qualifier

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface My1 {
}
```

Bean class

```
@ApplicationScoped
@My1
public class MyClass1 implements My {
    @Override
    public String turn() {
        return "1";
    }
}
```

The following unit test failed with empty beans list.

```
@QuarkusTest
public class MyTest {

  @Test
  public void test1() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(My.class, new AnnotationLiteral<My1>() {});
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(beans.isEmpty(), Is.is(false));
  }


  @Test
  public void test2() throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    // Class<? extends Annotation>
    final Class<? extends Annotation> annotationClass = My1.class;
    final Annotation qualifier = new Annotation() {

        @Override
        public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
            return annotationClass;
        }
    };
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(My.class, qualifier);
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(beans.isEmpty(), Is.is(false));
}
```

JUnit output for test1 and test2

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is <false>
     but: was <true>
Expected :is <false>
Actual   :<true>
```

Running the same sample in another Java library project works fine.

Adding an injected My attribute in the unit test class works fine too.

What could be wrong ?
What goes wrong with BeanManager in this example ?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely that your bean is considered *unused* and removed during the build. See https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#remove_unused_beans for more info.

You can try to annotate your bean with `@Unremovable`.

Also note that `BeanManager` is not meant to be used by the application code. It's an integration SPI. Moreover, Quarkus offers more idiomatic ways of integrating third party libraries and framework.